# Update query in createNativeQuery

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I want to run an `Update` query using `createNativeQuery` in entityManager. I am not able to run it.

My class structure :

```
class ABC_DAO
{

List<a> = entityManager.createNativeQuery(select.......); //sql1 : it is working fine

Sysout("some value"); // it is working


entityManager.createNativeQuery(update.......);// ***sql2 :it is not working***

Sysout("some value"); // it is working

}
```

Hibernate is not executing `sql2` but executing `sql2`. We are using Postgres db. This query has to be in Sql. We are using Hibernate with JPA.

Comment: I think you could have got answers if you posted more details. What SQL did you write? What exception did you get? What method did you call after creating native query?

Comment: Are you shure this is correct code? Method createNativeQuery returns not List.

Comment: "It is not working". LOL. I'll just have a look in the crystal ball ...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let my try to help you on behalf of your **erroneous** code example and problem description.

1) You will only get a `List` as result of a query if you call `getResultList()` on it, otherwise `sql1` would not work *(Please post the complete code, if you want to get help)*:

```
List<a> = entityManager.createNativeQuery("sql1", a.class).getResultList();
```

2) For update statements you have to call the method `executeUpdate()` and not `getResultList()` (or `getSingleResult()`)to send the native SQL statement to the database:

```
int countUpdated = entityManager.createNativeQuery("sql2").executeUpdate();
```